# Performing validation asp.net mvc without using models

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How do I do validation in mvc if I'm not using models?

I'm directly obtaining data from the controller and displaying it.

How do I validate? Most examples seem to use the model to validate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it is considered to be against MVC paradigm, nothing technically prevents you from working with the posted form directly.

```
class TestController : Controller
{
    [AcceptVerbs (HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult SomeAction (FormCollection form)
    {
        if (MyCustomValidation (form))
            SaveData ();

        RedirectToAction ("SomeAction");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you might want to have [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.post)] in your code:

```
class TestController : Controller
{
    [AcceptVerbs (HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult SomeAction (FormCollection form)
    {
        if (MyCustomValidation (form))
            SaveData ();

        RedirectToAction ("SomeAction");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a service layer as described by [this article](http://www.asp.net/learn/mvc/tutorial-38-cs.aspx), this allows both separation of concerns whilst maintaining error handling, not relying on the controller to do it all for you.

Comment: Great article. But if he's not using models then he's prob not gonna want to create a whole service layer